# Need help deciphering a formula for Projectile Motion

Tags: artificial-intelligence, physics, game-physics

I need to implement a bit of AI to figure out how to hit a target with projectile motion.

I found this over at wikipedia:

[Angle required to hit coordinate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trajectory_of_a_projectile#Angle_.CE.B8_required_to_hit_coordinate_.28x.2Cy.29)

Which looks like just the thing I need, especially since I have the added problem launching the projectile from above zero height. However, my maths skills aren't great so it all looks like complete nonsense to me and I have no idea how to translate any of it into code.

If anyone can break this down into something I can understand with basic operators (+ - * %) and functions (sin, cos, sqrt etc.), I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `xTarget/yTarget` is the position of the target, `xProj/yProj` the initial position of the projectile and `v` the initial velocity of the projectile (in meters per second), then the formula would translate to the following pseudo code:

```
x = xTarget - xProj;
y = yTarget - yProj;
g = 9.8;

tmp = pow(v, 4) - g * (g * pow(x, 2) + 2 * y * pow(v, 2));

if tmp < 0
   // no solution
else if x == 0
   angle1 = pi/2;
   if y < 0
      angle2 = -pi/2;
   else
      angle2 = pi/2;
   end
else
   angle1 = atan((pow(v, 2) + sqrt(tmp)) / (g * x));
   angle2 = atan((pow(v, 2) - sqrt(tmp)) / (g * x));
end
```

`g` is the graviational constant (~9.8 m/s^2), `atan` is the *arcus tangent* function and `pow` is the power function. The if-statement is necessary, because the formula can have no solution (if the target is not reachable with the initial velocity), one solution (then `angle1 == angle2`) or two solutions (as can be seen in [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/c/cd/Trajectory_for_changing_launch_angle.gif) animation; this is also why you have the +/- sign in the formula).

In most programming languages you will also find `atan2`, in which case you should be able to replace some code with

```
if tmp < 0
   // no solution
else
   angle1 = atan2(pow(v, 2) + sqrt(tmp), g * x);
   angle2 = atan2(pow(v, 2) - sqrt(tmp), g * x);
end
```

Comment: I think that you left out your atans.  Also, watch out for x = 0 (target is directly above you?)... divide by zero.

Answer (score 2):

The formula is quite simple, don't worry about the derivation.

```
x is the horizontal distance away of the target you're trying to hit
y is the vertical distance away of the target you're trying to hit
v is the initial velocity of the launch
g is the acceleration due to gravity (9.81 m/s on earth)
```

and the [formula on that link](http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/9/8/9/989f9cb1987b7736e916f87b8d9b2806.png) will give you the angle you need to launch the projectile in order to hit the target on the coordinate (x,y)